# Unfortunately application has stopped using google map api v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

**this is my log file**

```
04-01 17:21:32.460: E/dalvikvm(296): Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Builder', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
04-01 17:21:32.470: E/dalvikvm(296): Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tutos.android.gmapv2/com.tutos.android.gmapv2.MyMapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:582)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at com.tutos.android.gmapv2.MyMapActivity.onCreate(MyMapActivity.java:19)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  ... 11 more
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 7095000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzJ(Unknown Source)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzx.zzad(Unknown Source)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzx.zzac(Unknown Source)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zzqs(Unknown Source)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onInflate(Unknown Source)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:279)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:558)
04-01 17:21:32.651: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  ... 19 more
04-01 17:25:30.440: E/dalvikvm(305): Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Builder', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
04-01 17:25:30.460: E/dalvikvm(305): Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tutos.android.gmapv2/com.tutos.android.gmapv2.MyMapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:582)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.tutos.android.gmapv2.MyMapActivity.onCreate(MyMapActivity.java:19)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  ... 11 more
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 7095000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzJ(Unknown Source)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzx.zzad(Unknown Source)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzx.zzac(Unknown Source)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zzqs(Unknown Source)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onInflate(Unknown Source)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:279)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:558)
04-01 17:25:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  ... 19 more
```

Comment: Share the stack trace in a legible format, buddy. Prevent being downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

Your manifest.xml file is missing the below line, just add it and it should fix your problem.

Edit your application's AndroidManifest.xml file, and add the following declaration within the element. This embeds the version of Google Play services that the app was compiled with.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Android developers guide for more details https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: Thanks for the answer but where can i add the declaration i have a API key in the android:value ?

Comment: that is completely different meta-data. you need one with the api key to use maps and then you need this one to even use google play services library.

Comment: @abdelhakdalhoumi In the link I have pasted refer to **Obtain a Google Maps API key**. That explains how to obtain and use the key.

Comment: i did what you say and i add the <meta-data in the manifest.xml but i get this error in beginning of the log file :Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment', referenced from method com.tutos.android.gmapv2.MyMapActivity.onCreate